# Open VCF file after download complete in android from Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I have generated a Vcard in rails and set it to download by using the following code

```
  send_data Card.generate_vcard(asset).to_s, :filename => "contact.vcf", :type => "text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8",:disposition => 'attachment'
```

When someone goes to URL, the Vcard gets downloaded. But I also require that it automatically gets opened in phone's contacts app - or at least present an "Open with" option.

I followed this link http://lrvick.net/blog/accessibly_importing_vcards_from_qr_codes/ and went for second approach mentioned there, set the proper headers as well - but it is not work for me.

Thank you for Your Help

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, the file will just get downloaded.
You should also add a filename, such as

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="name_surname.vcf"
```

I noticed some browsers would not accept it as vCard otherwise.
Besides, this encourages the user to click on the downloaded file (and open it).

For Apple:
iOS now accepts vCard, for older version (> 4) you can cheat and embed the .vcf in a calendar .ics. [See this tutorial for more details](http://mobicontact.info/iphone/download-contact-from-web-page/)

For oldest version (<3) you must send the vCard by email..

For both, the best solution should would a [URI-Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) that would let us add a contact. But that is not available yet, even though I know iOS has some specific tools for that. 
We're waiting for a better HTML5 there :).